# Jquery mobile Swipe event not working with android chrome browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to detect swipeleft and swiperight events using jquery mobile.

```
$('#div1').on("swipeleft", function (event) {
    //some function
});

$('#div1').on("swiperight", function (event) {
    //some function
});
```

This works perfectly on iPad. But when I test it on adnroid chrome, this event get recognized very randomly. It detects this event sometimes and most of the time it is ignored.

I have gone through many threads on this, and tried many things like
 1. removing `e.preventDefault()` on touchStart event from jquery-ui-touch-punch library that I am using.
 2. mapping event on 'pageInit' etc

But nothing worked for me.
Is there any fix for this problem so that swipe event gets detected on mobile devices. Or is there any other to simulate swipe event programmatically.

Thanks.